# Prove that the reduction of HAM-CYCLE to TSP is polynomial-time?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, np, np-complete

This is a question that our professor uploaded yesterday, to prepare for our exam tomorrow. My problem with the question is part b (in boldface below); I'm not sure what I should do exactly.

> The Traveling Salesman Problem consists of a salesman and a set of cities. The salesman has to visit each one of the cities starting from a certain one (e.g. the hometown) and returning to the same city. The challenge of the problem is that the traveling salesman wants to minimize the total length of the trip.
>
> TSP = {(G, f, t): G = (V, E) a complete graph, f is a function V×V → Z, t ∈ Z, G is a graph that contains a traveling salesman tour with cost that does not exceed t}.
>
> Let the HAM-CYCLE problem defined as follows:  given an undirected graph G = (V, E), does there exist a simple cycle H that contains every node in V.
>
> Let a complete graph be a graph where there is an edge “between” every possible tuple of vertices.
>
> a-Define a certificate for TSP. Show that we can verify the certificate in deterministic polynomial time.
>
> **b-Prove that the reduction of HAM-CYCLE to TSP is polynomial-time.**
>
> c-Using the fact that HAM-CYCLE is NP-complete, what can we conclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only three differences between TSP and HAM-CYCLE as you've presented them:

- TSP assumes a complete graph, whereas HAM-CYCLE allows some pairs of vertices to not share an edge.
- TSP assigns a cost to every edge, whereas HAM-CYCLE treats all edges as equivalent.
- TSP seeks a tour that costs less than *t*, whereas HAM-CYCLE accepts any tour.

Given a graph *G* and an algorithm for solving TSP, we can solve HAM-CYCLE as follows:

- Construct a complete graph *G*′ with the same set of vertices as *G*.
- Let *f* (our cost function for TSP) return 0 whenever two vertices are adjacent in *G*, and 1 whenever they are not.
- Apply our TSP-solving algorithm to (*G*′, *f*, *t* = 0), and return the result. This will find whether there's a tour of *G*′ that only uses edges whose counterparts exist in *G*.

The above is a polynomial-time reduction from HAM-CYCLE to TSP. (Do you see why?)